# Problem accessing nested data from a GraphQL query in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-typescript

I've got a GraphQL query set up with the following structure, which I'm passing to React for rendering:

```
 {
  events{
    id
    name
    startDate
    endDate
    subscribedUsers{
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I have two specific problems:

1. In one view I have a table where I want to show the event details and the number of subscribed Users. When I console.log subscribed Users it looks like an array, it doesn't have a `.length` property I can reference and I can't seems to apply array methods to it to get the length. When I try to render it with

`{props.event.subscribedUsers.length}`

I get the error `Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string; }'.ts(2339)`

2. In a second view of a single event's details I want to map the names of the users to a child component for rendering, but because it does not seem to be a true array the mapping doesn't work:

   `{props.subscribedUsers.map((attendee: attendeeType) => {...}}`

returns a similar error `Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ id: string; name: string; }'.ts(2339)`

Is there a way I can convert the subscribed Users data into an array I can access normally or how can I best get at the data?

Thanks for any help. Mark

Comment: look at data/network response (show fragment!?) - this query can return both object and an array, sometimes it's can be [missleading] an object if only one record exists, depends on specific API behaviour/specs - test/check in playground before coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually pointed the reason. Look at the schema - the error prompts that the data is NOT an array. It is a plain Object which you can access with simple dot notation such as:

```
{props.subscribedUsers.id} or   {props.subscribedUsers.name}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So I should be able to turn `{props.subscribedUsers}` into an array using `Object.entries()` and then I can map over it. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Check if you will succeed, no need to turn it into array, unless you have to. Please accept the solution in case the above works that helps the rest of the communicty.